# A change in eventFilter function causes weird QGraphicScene behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a Qt program with a QGraphicScene inside a QGraphicsView on top of QMainWindow.
The events are handled by the QMainWindow using an eventFilter function.
The function body looks similar to this code:

```
bool Window::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *event) {
  QEvent::Type type = event->type();

  if (type == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);

    switch(keyEvent->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_A:
    case Qt::Key_B:
    case Qt::Key_C:
    case Qt::Key_D:
      // call a function that uses the current mouse position on the graphics scene
      break;
    default:
      QLocale loc = QApplication::keyboardInputLocale();
      if(loc.language() != QLocale::English) {
        QString message = "A non-English key was pressed";
        showMessage(message, QMessageBox::Warning);
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

I recently added the "default" part and since then the coordinates that are used in the A,B,C,D cases are totally wrong. In addition, if I add a simple cout print anywhere in the function the bug disappears and the correct mouse coordinates are used.

What can possibly cause this?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like memory/stack corruption problem. "Added random call, stuff fixed itself" is very often a sign of this. Is it possible that you are using uninitialized members or pointers anywhere? Try running your code through CppCheck utility. (won't hurt anyway)

Comment: Post the code that gets the mouse location. Better yet, post the minimum code that actually demostrate the problem.

Comment: @StephenChu I don't think that the problem is in the code that gets the mouse location, since I didn't change it at all.

Comment: @Zeks you might be right - I did have a memory corruption problem before, which I ignored after spending too much time on. I tried to use Memory Validator on windows and valgrind on linux. I'll try to use CppCheck or a similar program, but I don't think I'll help too much.