# Calling an inline function from an inline function call?

Tags: c++, qt, inline

I noticed that both std::min and std::max are inlined in the stl_algobase.h header and I'm wondering if a line like this can be problematic to (any, but especially gcc) compiler:

```
a = std::max(b, std::min(c, d));
```

What actually happens here when this expression is inlined?

---

**Explanation:**

I've had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297478/a-change-in-eventfilter-function-causes-weird-qgraphicscene-behavior) bug that didn't make sense at all. I traced the error to these lines:

```
float mouseScenePosX = mouseEvent->scenePos().x();
mouseScenePosX = max((float)0,
    min(mouseScenePosX, (float)scene->getSceneRect().width()-1));
```

I always get 0 in mouseScenePosX, although both mouseScenePosX and scene->getSceneRect().width()-1 are larger than 0.
Strangely, when I removed the -O2 flag from the makefile the bug disappeared, and also, when I used my own min and max implementations.
So, I'm wondering whether it can be caused by an error in the inlining.

Comment: Why don't you go to disassembly and check? Anyway, it shouldn't be problematic, inline functions behave much better than macros.

Comment: @Bartek Banchewicz Hmm... How do you do that?

Comment: `g++ -S code.cpp -o code.asm`

Comment: Why do you think there would be a problem?

Comment: @Als had a bug that made me suspicious

Comment: You should post the detail of the bug and the problem that makes you suspicious, preferably a small minimalistic code sample.Right now the question doesn't make much of a sense and the only answer you can get is **"YES/NO"** which won't really help in anyway.

Comment: I looked at the other bug and cannot see anything wrong there either. Maybe the `scene` pointer? Note otherwise that (float)0 could also be written 0.0f.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke The pointer is not Null or wrong in any way. The "bug" in the link was fixed by simply splitting the function and I can't understand why...

Comment: Maybe min and max are macros then. You may want to use std::min() and std::max() to make sure you're using the inline functions. (in your example with the mouse coordinate you don't use std::)

Comment: And if `min`/`max` are macros, the using `std::min` will fail to compile, which is good. Then you can look up what the special Microsoft define is to disable the definition of those macros. I always forget it.

Comment: #define NOMINMAX before including Windows.h

Comment: @Alexis Wilke min and max are not macros - there are "using std::min/max" declarations elsewhere.

Comment: @Retired Ninja Why do I need to use this macro?

Comment: Those lines look suspiciously innocent. Since the problem goes away if you remove optimizations, it's possible that the cause lies elsewhere. Post the entire function.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't think that there is a problem with this specific function - it works perfectly fine when I split it to two different functions.

Comment: @White Zebra You probably don't need them, I was just helping Steve Jessop remember what he was thinking of.  You'll know if you do, because std::min and std::max will give you some really nice compile errors if the Windows min/max macros are defined.

Answer (score 3):

It is guaranteed to behave as if it make a function call.  Any inlining the compiler does, if any, absolutely must result in the same thing that would if no inlining were done.

In other words, your example code should work exactly as you'd expect it to, return the max of comparing b to the min of comparing c to d.

If you find a compiler that violates this, throw it away.

I've never seen a GCC bug regarding this kind of thing.  Never seen a bug regarding inlines at all actually.

Comment: In addition, this kind of "inline nesting" provides a lot of optimization potential for the compiler, since instead of having to call an external function that it doesn't know anything about, it will actually create a larger, "flat" piece of code that it can shuffle around and optimize.

Comment: The first bit is technically incorrect. Formally, it must result in _"something that could occur if no inlining were done"_. E.g. it's explicitly and intentionally unspecified when copy constructors are elided. Inlining may alter this in undocumented ways. But since you couldn't rely on this elision either way, it doesn't matter how it's altered either.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding parenthesis in the last parameter:

getSceneRect().width()-1)));
?>

If it then works *better*, then min/max are not the std::min and std::max.

It does not make sense that it would work better if split because the std::min and std::max are functions (inline or not) and the calling convention just cannot break.